# Couldn't create database in Postgresql

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql-9.3

I am trying to create a new database in postgres on my company's backup server.

I tried both from pgadmin and command line but i am getting this following error:

```
Error: could not read file "base/1/1187" : Input/Output error
```

Running OS on server is Ubuntu server edition.

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to a Postgresql crash or disk fault.

You might try looking in the kernel log to see if there's any more info there

Before doing anything read this:

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Corruption

Once you've done that, then you can look into possible repairs. You'll probably have some significant data loss, so your goal should be to get it working to the point where you can pg_dump the damaged databases, re-initdb, and reload.

If you have a recent backup, now would be a good time to think about using it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a file in the template database `template1` that PostgreSQL cannot access.

Maybe somebody messed with the data directory, maybe a file system check after an integrity problem got rid of it. Any unusual occurrences like crashes recently?

Anything in `/var/log/messages` or in the PostgreSQL server log?

Is the file present? If yes, what does `ls -l 1187` show?

To find out which table is affected, you can install the contribs and run

```
oid2name -d template1 -f 1187
```